# How to sign APK in release mode in VS 2017 native app?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017, native

How to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode in Visual Studio Native-Activity Application (Android) project?

When I rebuild solution and deploy solution in release ARM target, navigate to Release folder and drag and drop apk file to play.google.com (Play Store), there is following error message.

Upload failed

You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs or Android App Bundles.

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Learn more about signing.

I have manged to generate and download deployment_cert.der on play store, but not sure how it can be added to apk in Visual Studio Native-Activity Application (Android) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figered it out now.
Built APK file can be signed by using command line (without need of installing Android Studio). This can be done as follows:

1.) Bellow will allow to build unsigned APK in release mode:

`.packing project Properties --> Ant --> Ant Build Target --> Release (Release Mode)`

2.) Add JDK and Android SDK to PATH. In my case (installed by VS installer) those paths are:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3`

3.) Create keystore with key:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my_app.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg PSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

4.) Sign APK:

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my_app.keystore My.App.Packaging-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`

5.) ZIP align:

`zipalign -f -v 4 My.App.Packaging-release-unsigned.apk My.App.apk`

6.) Drag and drop to Play Store